# Unable to fetch getBalance of eth address

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am unable to get the balance of an eth address using `web3.eth.getBalance`, it returns error like "no suitable peers available". I connected the eth mainnet in light node.

**My source code:**

```
web3.eth.getBalance(to_address, function (err, ethbalance) {
   var balance = ethbalance;
   if (err) {
      res.json({status: false,message: err.message});
   }
   else{
      res.json({status: true,message: balance});
   }
});
```

Please suggest me solutions to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be an issue on your code, but rather about your setup in which you don't have peers to connect in your configuration files.

You may try to [update your peer nodes](https://gist.github.com/rfikki/e2a8c47f4460668557b1e3ec8bae9c11).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try